# Change the connection string to SQL Server so that every team member can connect without problems

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET Core to develop the web. I have a connection string in `appsettings.json` as follows

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-RDB3EOL;Initial Catalog=library_pou;Integrated Security=True"

  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The problem is when my development team is constantly having problems with the wrong connection chain. They have to change 'data Source' to their server name.
there is a way to change the SQL Server connection string so that they can run on every different server without problems. Give me a solution please.

Comment: Put a single development database instance on a shared server, and set the connection string to point to that instance. Then everyone can share the same connection string without having to change it at all.

Comment: Right, I thought they were having trouble connecting to _your_ desktop. Which would make sense if they couldn't resolve your workstation name through AD or punch through a firewall or whatever. If they each have their own local, independent copy of the database you're all clearly working on, why? Like Ken suggests, put the database on a shared server you can all reach and call it a day.

Comment: …or if the developers really need to have independent copies, what is the problem? Shouldn’t they each have their own copy of settings/config files that they have to change exactly once and can be maintained separately from the rest of the app? Or if you’re sharing an appsettings file that gets changed centrally, can’t you pull the connection string from a _different_ file that is unique to each dev? Or if everyone has a default instance just change the config file to say localhost instead of hard-coding each dev’s workstation name? This just shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: To add to Aaron's ors: ...or use appsettings.Development.json files in which individual developers keep their customizations ...or come up with a common host name such as `app_db_server` to use in the appsettings.json files and create a corresponding lookup for it on each developer's/staging/production C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\HOSTS file.

Comment: Did you try to use localhost or just . dot instead of mashine name?

Comment: Put the connection string in UserSecrets, not the main app settings- user secrets are not merged into source control so you don't end up overwriting everyone else's settings when you push